# Keyboard shortcut to switch selection from CANCEL to CONTINUE

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I know the keyboard shortcut to select between `Dont Save`, `Cancel`, and `Save` ie.

> Save -> `enter`
>
> Cancel -> ⌘ + `.`
>
> Dont Save -> ⌘ + `delete`

I also know we can switch between DontSave-Cancel-Save or Cancel-Continue by activating this:

```
System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> All controls
```

What is keyboard shortcut to select `Continue` when the default is at `Cancel`? I tried ⌘ + `enter` but failed.

[image]

OS: **Mac OS X 10.12**

_note: I am OK with my question moved to AskDifferent if that's a better place to ask for macOS related questions.

Comment: This is very much depend on your system and may there be app level differences too. Please specify at least OS. In windows I'd use TAB or Shift+TAB if one of the options is already selected.

Answer (score 2):

The place where you set that setting has text describing how to use it:

[image: press Tab to move keyboard focus]

So, like it says at the end of the first line, you can hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key (some keyboards show the tab symbol  <kbd>⇥</kbd> instead of the word "tab") to move the focus ring from one control (e.g. button) to the next. Hit <kbd>space</kbd> to activate the control (e.g. press the button) that the focus ring is currently on.

Comment: that's not what I meant. I meant in the selection between `Cancel` and `Continue`, what is the keyboard shortcut to select `Continue` automatically.

Comment: "Continue" is not a terribly common button, so there is no universal single keyboard shortcut (key-chord) to hit it. Instead, it takes just two keystrokes in the scenario in the screenshot you posted: tab and then space.